# How can I create a data frame with all existing variables (at once)?

Tags: r, dataframe, r-environment

It may sound trivial and the solution is probably quite simple but I can't figure it out.

I just want to combine all my variables in a `data.frame`. I wonder if there is a way to do that without choosing them one by one, but instead telling R that I want to use all of the already existing variables?

```
var1 <- c(1,2)
var2 <- c(3,4)
```

Instead of doing this

```
df <- data.frame(var1, var2)
```

I want to do something like this

```
df <- data.frame(-ALL_VARIABLES_IN_ENVIRONMENT-)
```

I've tried `ls()` (respectively `objects()`) also in combinatination with `unquote()` as well as `names()` but this only gives me a vector with names (undquoted or not) and not the environment's objects.

Comment: You can do `do.call(data.frame, mget(ls()))` or `as.data.frame(mget(ls()))`.

Comment: @27ϕ9: Thanks, that worked pretty well :) The 2nd way is a little bit more intuitve, at least for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var1 <- 1:3
var2 <- 1:3

data.frame(sapply(ls(), get))

#   var1 var2
# 1    1    1
# 2    2    2
# 3    3    3
```